# How do you make this shape in Python with nested loops?

Tags: python

Write a program using nested loops to draw this pattern. (14) bottom page

Comment: please explain *how* are you having trouble with it? Do you not understand what the question is asking (i.e. nested for loops, etc)? Please *type* or copy the *text* into your question so we don't have to dig through a pdf file to find question 14..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Comment: In particular, posting "please do my homework for me" is *way* out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in range(6):                 # this outer loop computes each of the 6 lines
   line_to_print = '#'
   for num_spaces in range(row):     # this inner loop adds the desired number or spaces to the line
       line_to_print  = line_to_print + ' '
   line_to_print = line_to_print + '#'
   print line_to_print
```

prints this output:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```